# Github Actions : Reusable workflow across multiple organizations

Tags: cicd, github, build-pipeline, github-actions

I have a query in regards with Github workflows.

Consider the below scenario :

- Github Organization 1 : **sample_one**
- Github Organization 2 : **sample_two**
- sample_one organization has one repository called : **one_repo**
- sample_two organization has one repository called : **two_repo**

**Problem Statement :**

one_repo has a reusable workflow that needs to be called by two_repo (that is in different organization) - How do I do this?

Note :

The reusable workflow from one_repo maybe updated from time to time.

Can someone help me with the workflow calls for the same as to how can a repo from some other organization be able to call the resuable workflow from another organization.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must permit the reusable workflow to be called from another organization. 
For that, go to *Organization settings -> Actions -> General*. Under the policies, select the "**Allow all actions and reusable workflows**" option to use the workflow outside the organization.

**NOTE**: You have to keep the repositories public so that the other organizations can access them.

[image: org-settings]

**Now to the work:**

1. Create a reusable workflow in the GitHub Organization 1: ***sample_one***.
2. Now create a trigger workflow in ***two_repo*** to call the workflow in ***one_repo*** under ***sample_one*** organization.
3. Now add the trigger parameter under the ***jobs*** section inside the workflow and mention the reusable workflow of ***one_repo***.

```json
name: Scan, Build and Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  trigger:
    uses: sample_one/one_repo/.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@main
```

Edit the following line according to the location of the reusable workflow.

That's it! So when the workflow runs in the ***two_repo***, the reusable workflow in the ***one_repo*** will be used.